# textview color is not changing on calling notifydatasetchange?

Tags: android

I am just trying to  change color of textview on notifydatasetchanged but it is not changing.

I need to call server at some intervals and need to update the list accordingly.txtview color is reflecting firsttime only.After calling notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter it doesnt change any thing.

Comment: Are you sure `mo.playername` has the expected value? You should output a log message to be sure. My guess is that the `MyData` object you have in your view holder is not the one you are updating before calling `notifyDatasetChanged()`.

Comment: i did a lot debugging and also tried it different if-else condtion to change it but failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
R.color.white
```

is a resource, it doesn't give the color.

so you might have to get the color.

```
int col = context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white);
mvh.txtview.setTextColor(col);
```

you need to know the context.

Comment: Alternatively, use mvh.txtview.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); to avoid needing the context/resources for simple colors that already exist

Comment: I dont know why it happens but your solution works for me.                 Thanks

Comment: It happens because, as @YashwanthKumar said, R.color.white is not an actual color. It is, essentially, a link to a resource that contains that color. So by setting the color to R.color.white, you are setting it to the link value (some random integer) and not the actual color value. The reason this works is because resources are identified by an integer ID and setTextColor accepts integers. I'm surprised it doesn't just crash for it being an invalid color. by calling context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white) you are telling your code to load the color value stored within that resource.